# Using PostgreSQL from ASP.Net vNext

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Preview and created an ASP.Net 5 Empty Project.

I 'll use PostgreSQL in my application, so I added "Npgsql" NuGet Package in my project.

I added "using Npgsql" and tried to write a simple SQL connection test method but I get the error below :

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Npgsql' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   WebApplication3.ASP.NET Core 5.0    AccountsController.cs

My project.json file :

```
 "dependencies"
: {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "EnterpriseLibrary.Data": "6.0.1304.0",
    "Npgsql": "2.2.3.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "System.Data.Common": "1.0.0-beta1"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {},
    "aspnetcore50": { }
}
```

Is there any mistake or is it not possible to connect Postgres using asp.net-vnext right now ?

Besides, we want to develope code on Visual Studio and run on Ubuntu and we will have to use some third parties. Is it right time to go on with asp.net-vNext or choose some other open source language?

It feels like asp.net-vnext needs time to use in a project like that..

Comment: Have you tried to remove the line  "aspnetcore50": { } ?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to run it in Ubuntu just yet. Not sure that  "EnterpriseLibrary.Data": "6.0.1304.0", is compatible with aspnetcore50.

Comment: Bare in mind that EF7 still has a lot of features to be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to remove the line "aspnetcore50": { } ? 
I'm not sure you'll be able to run it in Ubuntu just yet. Not sure that "EnterpriseLibrary.Data": "6.0.1304.0", is compatible with aspnetcore50. 
Also if you use Entity Framework, keep in mind that EF7 still has a lot of features to be implemented.

I also wanted to create an application to be used both in Win and Lin but decided to go with windows only for now an leave it open enough so will be easy to change it later to support both OS. Do let you be mistaken with the false advertize of multiplatform (it's just marketing), this is not fully supported for big enterprise applications, not yet. I truly believe it will be soon, well I hope, I had the chance to go with Python tech but kept with .NET, I hope I haven't made a huge mistake.

Good luck.

Comment: It works when I remove "aspnetcore50": { }. Thanks for sharing opinions also.

Comment: you're welcome. btw, if you need to remove aspnetcore50 to have an app working that might mean that you won't be able to execute that app in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Just move whole "**dependency**" block under "**aspnet50**". Here is complete example of [using PostgreSQL from ASP.NET 5](http://druss.co/2015/04/vnext-use-postgresql-fluent-nhibernate-from-asp-net-5-dnx-on-ubuntu/)